# Return the first index from second table in INNER JOIN SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following tables and would like to write a SQL query to return the first result from the second table which matches the inner join.

```
Cars
id  brand       model
1   Ford        Mustang
2   Audi        A4
3   BMW         3

Images
id  img_url                                         car_id
1   https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/ford_1.jpg     1
2   https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/ford_2.jpg     1
3   https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/audi_1.jpg     2
4   https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/audi_2.jpg     2
5   https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/audi_3.jpg     2
6   https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/bmw_1.jpg      3
7   https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/bmw_2.jpg      3
```

I'm doing an INNER JOIN on cars.id = images.car_id, but can't seem to find a way to limit the result from the Images Table to the first row that matches cars.id to images.car_id.

Ideally, I'd like this to be returned:

```
id  brand       model       img_url
1   Ford        Mustang     https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/ford_1.jpg 
2   Audi        A4          https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/audi_1.jpg 
3   BMW         3           https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/bmw_1.jpg
```

Any help is much appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses `row_number()`

```
select i.*
from cars c join
     (select i.*,
             row_number() over (partition by car_id order by id) as seqnum
      from images i
     ) i
     on i.car_id = c.id
where seqnum = 1;
```

Another method moves all the filtering to the `where` clause:

```
select i.*
from images i
where exists (select 1
              from cars c
              where i.car_id = c.id
             ) and
      i.id = (select min(i2.id)
              from images i2
              where i2.car_id = i.car_id
             );
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Gordon! Filtering through the `where` clause did the trick